# Bootstrap 4.1 grid-layout is wider than the page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, grid-layout

I'm using Bootstrap 4.1 for my page but when I insert a grid-layout, it's wider than the page, making the user scroll sideways to view the whole  grid.

Page Before Grid-System:
https://ibb.co/y8RWGqY

Page After Grid-System:
https://ibb.co/LPP0TsL

```css
.carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 350px;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.logo img {
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
}

.titulo {
  display: inline;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<header>
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/LAaSoL0LrYs/1920x1080')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h2 class="display-4">First Slide</h2>
          <p class="lead">This is a description for the first slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/bF2vsubyHcQ/1920x1080')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h2 class="display-4">Second Slide</h2>
          <p class="lead">This is a description for the second slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Slide Three - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/szFUQoyvrxM/1920x1080')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h2 class="display-4">Third Slide</h2>
          <p class="lead">This is a description for the third slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="logo">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
</div>

<br><br><br>

<main style="text-align: center;">
  <div class="titulo">Quem somos</div>
</main>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4" style="background-color: red;"><br><br><br><br><br></div>
  <div class="col-8" style="background-color: blue;"><br><br><br><br><br></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a mix of both solution, you should use `container-fluid` class to the grid container in order to make it 100% width.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
   
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4" style="background-color: red;"><br><br><br><br><br></div>
        <div class="col-8" style="background-color: blue;"><br><br><br><br><br></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add **container-fluid** above of row div or you can also remove scroll without add container div so add **m-0** class in row

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
                <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('images/c1.jpg')">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h2 class="display-4">First Slide</h2>
                        <p class="lead">This is a description for the first slide.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
                <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('images/c2.jpg')">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h2 class="display-4">Second Slide</h2>
                        <p class="lead">This is a description for the second slide.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Slide Three - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
                <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('images/c3.jpg')">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h2 class="display-4">Third Slide</h2>
                        <p class="lead">This is a description for the third slide.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.png">
    </div>

    <br><br><br>

    <main style="text-align: center;">
        <div class="titulo">Quem somos</div>
    </main>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4" style="background-color: red;"><br><br><br><br><br></div>
        <div class="col-8" style="background-color: blue;"><br><br><br><br><br></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That way it doesn't fill the page, I would like it to be 100% width. Also md-0 puts a  col on top of the other.

Comment: because row class is set  margin-right: -15px; and  margin-left: -15px; so.

Comment: How can I change it?

Comment: are you remove  margin from row class in throughout project and bootstrap 4 ?

Comment: If you change only particular section than you choose perent div class than set .example .row { margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0; }

Comment: If you can remove margin from bootstrap 4 so you can set top of the your custom style

.row { margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0; }

Comment: Please check you link css order first link bootstrap css than your custom css and put .row { margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0; } in your custom css

Comment: No need to add vendor prefix to transform property like you did here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57562422/8620333 ... it's no more needed since too long. Transform is now supported in all the browsers:

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to remember is, you should put all your contents in a div with class of container or container-fluid. as bellow:

```
<div class="container">
your code goes here...
</div>
```

Comment: As I have said before, I want it to be 100% wide, that way it gets smaller than 100%

Comment: using 'container-fluid' class can help you